# Dynamic SQL: how to handle single quote in select statement

Tags: dynamic, plsql

Basically I want to search for an employee from a database using his/her job title and location. I write a function name searchemp using dynamic sql (dbms_sql.v7).

Table structure

Emp table:

```
Empno number
Ename varchar
Job   varchar
Deptno number
```

Dept table

```
DEPTNO number
DNAME  varchar        
LOC    varchar
```

So my select statement looks like this:

```
  select_stm:= 'SELECT * FROM emp FULL OUTER JOIN dept ON emp.deptno =   dept.deptno where job = ' || UPPER(e_job) || ' and loc = ' || UPPER(e_loc);
```

- UPPER is used because everything in these two tables are uppercase.
- The function name is called like this

  ```
  SQL> execute searchemp('&job', '&loc');
  Enter value for job: clerk
  Enter value for loc: dallas
  ```

When I displayed the sql statement on the screen:

```
   SELECT * FROM emp FULL OUTER JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno where job = CLERK and loc = DALLAS;
```

I have the error invalid identifier for CLERK and DALLAS. Also there is no single quote around CLERK and DALLAS so it can't find any employee in the database.The function works fine if the parameter is number (i.e.empno).

The sql statement is good as I tested it in SQL*Plus.
How can I handle the single quote so that it displays what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazarding a few guesses here, because its very weird its not picking up the single quotes.:

firstly, the SQL was missing a single quote at the end. Any reason you use the pipes ||?

```
select_stm:= 'SELECT * FROM emp FULL OUTER JOIN dept ON emp.deptno =   dept.deptno where job = ' || UPPER(e_job) || ' and loc = ' || UPPER(e_loc) || ';
```

Does same error occur if you use a like statement like below?

```
select_stm:= 'SELECT * FROM emp FULL OUTER JOIN dept ON emp.deptno =   dept.deptno where job like '% || UPPER(e_job) || %' and loc and '% || UPPER(e_loc) %';
```

Comment: I use the pipes || because there are single quote around the variable e_job and e_loc (I forgot to put the single quotes in select stm above)